# No size limitation while uploading the file to server in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Here i am doing upload the any file(there is no file size restriction and user can upload the  any file extension) to server through my php code (in codigniter) but when I am trying to upload the file which is size 185MB so it is giving me error.
 I also add the php.ini to my folder structure on server which is got from my server support. I did increased the upload size and also increases another related attribute. I can upload the file which is size 20MB but did not able to upload the file size 50mb, 100mb, etc. upload maximum file size working on localhost but not working on server. 
Please below is the my code. Please help me any changes in my code

upload the files through ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>files>',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType :'json',
            xhr: function() {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(myXhr.upload){
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progress, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            beforeSend:function() { 
                $("#progressbar").show();
                $("#cmdSub").attr("disabled",true);
                $("#cmdSub").val("Please Wait");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.success != ""){
                    location.href = "<?php echo base_url();?>files/";
                }
                if(data.error != ""){
                    $("#f_name").val("");
                    $("#fnameinfo").html(data.error);
                    $("#cmdSub").attr("disabled",false);
                    $("#cmdSub").val("Submit");
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                alert("Error while uploading");
                $("#cmdSub").attr("disabled",false);
                $("#cmdSub").val("Submit");
                $("#ffileinfo").html("");
            },
            data: formdata,
            // this is the important stuf  need to overide the usual post behavior
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
```

controller code

```
function uploadFile() {

        $f_name = $_FILES['f_name']['name'];
         $f_type = $_FILES['f_name']['type'];
         $f_size = $_FILES['f_name']['size'];
        $f_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['f_name']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['f_name']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME );
        $filename = str_replace($arr_chars,"_",$filename);

        $configFile = array (
                'allowed_types' => '*',
                'upload_path'   => $file_upload_path,
                'file_name'     => $filename.'_'.$fid
            );

        $this->upload->initialize($configFile);

        if($this->upload->do_upload('f_name')) {
            //insert the record
        } else {
                $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

File upload size is probably a server config issue :)

Try this in your php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

--Edit (Thanks Big Chris)

The script could time out handling this request. So you should add this to your function

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 120);
```

This tells php that this file can take up to 2 minutes to run

Hope that helps :)

Comment: The script may also be timing out and is being killed by the webserver.

Comment: I did already change the upload_max_filesize = 4000M
post_max_size = 4000M on server.

Comment: Did you set the max_execution_time?

Comment: actually what happen when I upload the file which is size 150MB so all progress bar is loaded completely then after that i got alert("error while uploading") in error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError).

Comment: i set the max_execution_time = 20000 in php.ini

Comment: Is your upload directory writable?

Comment: If it can upload small files that would not be the problem

Comment: Can I ask what webserver you are using? You may have to restart it